# Can I call an event handler with a parameter using inline declaration of the parameter without having the function be recreated on every render?

Tags: reactjs

As I have understood it the following way to call an event handler is

`+` compact and simple to read

`-`, but causes a new `myWrapperFunc` function to be created on every render

However, creating functions is cheap right? That that minus is insignificant, right?

Am I correct in my understanding that this way to pass an event handler with a parameter will not cause a new `handler` instance to be created on each render?

```
handler(event, val) {
    ...
}

<Component onClick={myWrapperFunc = (e) => handler(e, "myVal")}>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you are passing the function wrong. It should be:

```
<Component onClick={(e) => handler(e, "myVal")}>
```

If we talk about the main question, I'm not an expert but there is still not an agreement on this subject. There is a reality that your callback function is created in every render and this causes a performance loss. But how significant is this loss? This depends on your app probably.

Is it a big app which includes so many components that create callbacks like that. So, you should consider an optimization then. Some people say if you don't need optimization then don't bother with it :) Some says follow the best practices.

You can pass parameters to your functions without using them like that but somehow you should get these parameters in your component. If it is a prop then use it directly instead of passing it like that for example. Then use a separate function and its reference. You don't need to pass `e` for a callback, it is passed by automatically with callbacks.

```
handler () => {
    use(event);
    use(props.val);
    use(val_variable_in_component;
...
}

..
<Component onClick={handler}>
```

Comment: Thanks for an informative answer! FYI, I was not passing the function wrong. I just wanted to pass a named function, which is unconventional, to be able to refer to it in my text.

Comment: You are welcome. Could you pass a named function like that? :)